# Back button on a Tableau Worksheet

Tags: tableau-api

I am building a dashboard in tableau that navigates to different worksheets. I am wondering if there is a way to add a back button to a worksheet. I have thought of one way using an action filter menu, but that method is not very user friendly. Is there a way to get a button or something more obvious to the user? Thanks

Comment: What do you want the back button to do? I'm guessing you want a button than does something different from the browser back button.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add navigation button with action filter. There is no other way to add button till now. I hope tableau soon add the official way to add button in the dashboard.